# limit of multivariable piecewise function(calculus)

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, piecewise-continuity

I got a piecewise function defined as $$f(x,y)= \begin{cases}   1, & 0<y<x^2\\ 0, &\quad\; \;\text{else} \end{cases}$$

How to find $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}f(x,y)$ along the $y=mx$ path ?

Besides, why does $n$ needed to bigger than or equal to zero for the following limit exist : 
$$\lim_{x \to a}g(x)^n=\lim_{ x\to a}[g(x)]^n$$

Thank you so much

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your questions lacks details and context. Why are you interested in this question and what have you tried so far? You can find some remarks about how to ask a good question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

For your $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)$ let's first consider this area.  Here's a sketch of the region where $0<y<x^2$.

[image]

So we know that $f(x,y)$ is $1$ in the shaded region and it's $0$ everywhere else.  Keep in mind, the area is $0<y<x^2$ so any point that lies on the line $y=0$ or $y=x^2$ will NOT be in this region, and our function will take the value of $0$ at these points.

---

What we want to do is think about the value of $f(x,y)$ for $(x,y)$ pairs very close to $(0,0)$ that lie on the $y=mx$ path.  For any $m \neq 0$, there will be an $x \neq 0$ small enough so that $mx>x^2$ when $mx$ is positive.  Clearly $mx$ could be negative if either $m$ or $x$ is negative.  Since $m$ and $x$ are non-zero, we can then say that for $x$ values that are very close to $0$, our path $y=mx$ will always give us $mx<0$ or $mx>x^2$.

If $mx$ is always greater than $x^2$ or less than $0$ for $x$ values near $0$, then we can also say $y$ is always greater than $x^2$ or less than $0$ for $x$ values near $0$ (since $y=mx$).

This all assumed that $m \neq 0$.  If instead $m=0$, then our path would be $y=0$.  We already determined that $y=0$ is not in the shaded region.

---

Therefore, the path $y=mx$ does not lie in the shaded region for $x$ values very close to $0$.  And for any $m$, if $x$ is very close to $0$, then so is $y$ when we're on this path.  All of this means that $f(x,y)=0$ for all $(x,y)$ pairs very close to $(0,0)$ that also lay on the path $y=mx$.

You will also notice that as $x$ approaches $0$ and continues to get smaller, all of the above inequalities hold up.  All this means is that $f(x,y)$ will continue to take on the value of $0$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$.  Therefore, $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}f(x,y)=0.$$